# ffmpeg vaapi and drawtext

Tags: ffmpeg, vaapi

Simple question like hell:
Is it possible to use hardware accelerated transcoding with ffmpeg, Intel CPU and VAAPI using text overlay with drawtext?

My current working command without drawtext is:

```
ffmpeg -vaapi_device /dev/dri/card0 -hwaccel vaapi -hwaccel_output_format vaapi  -i /file.mp4 -vf 'format=vaapi|nv12,hwupload' -threads 8 -vcodec h264_vaapi -acodec copy -scodec copy  -b:v 3000k /file2.mp4
```

but it seems hwaccel and drawtext filter cannot coexist, at least as it seems at a first glance.

Comment: Should not be a problem. Insert drawtext before the format.

Comment: This i what I get when I use both drawtext and format:
`Impossible to convert between the formats supported by the filter 'graph 0 input from stream 0:1' and the filter 'auto_scaler_0'`

Comment: You'll have to set the hwaccel_output_format to nv12 or yuv420p

Comment: YES. That's it!  `hwaccel_output_format  nv12` did the trick. Thank you very very much!

Comment: @ViktorJoras can you share the final command which worked for you.