# ffmpeg vaapi (intel) hardware decode, drawbox, hardware encode

Tags: ffmpeg, vaapi

So I am running a go2rtc server and I'm receiving a rtsp stream from a camera and I want to draw a box on top of the video. The system has a Pentium Silver J5005 with iGPU. From what I understand I should be able to use `hwmap` instead of `hwdownload/hwupload` in this case because the iGPU and CPU share the same system memory. Anyway, leaving out the drawing part, I can tell that hardware decoding and encoding is working because `ffmpeg` only uses about 8% CPU. This is the ffmpeg command that I have working, but it is only decoding and re-encoding the video:

```
ffmpeg -hide_banner -v error -allowed_media_types video -loglevel verbose -hwaccel vaapi -hwaccel_output_format vaapi -hwaccel_device /dev/dri/renderD128 \
  -i rtsp://... -c:v h264_vaapi -g 50 -bf 0 -profile:v high -level:v 4.1 -sei:v 0 -an \
  -filter_complex "[0:v]scale_vaapi,hwmap=mode=read+write+direct,format=nv12[in];\
    [in]format=vaapi|nv12,hwmap[out]" -map "[out]" \
  -c:v h264_vaapi -an -user_agent ffmpeg/go2rtc -rtsp_transport tcp -f rtsp rtsp://..."
```

Now i'm trying to insert a `drawbox` filter:

```
ffmpeg -hide_banner -v error -allowed_media_types video -loglevel verbose -hwaccel vaapi -hwaccel_output_format vaapi -hwaccel_device /dev/dri/renderD128 \
  -i rtsp://... -c:v h264_vaapi -g 50 -bf 0 -profile:v high -level:v 4.1 -sei:v 0 -an \
  -filter_complex "[0:v]scale_vaapi,hwmap=mode=read+write+direct,format=nv12[in];\
    [in]drawbox=x=10:y=10:w=100:h=100:color=pink@0.5:t=fill[in2];\
    [in2]format=vaapi|nv12,hwmap[out]" -map "[out]" \
  -c:v h264_vaapi -an -user_agent ffmpeg/go2rtc -rtsp_transport tcp -f rtsp rtsp://...
```

But this fails immedicately:

```
[h264 @ 0x55bf016ffc40] Reinit context to 2304x1296, pix_fmt: vaapi
[graph 0 input from stream 0:0 @ 0x55bf01fe9100] w:2304 h:1296 pixfmt:vaapi tb:1/90000 fr:20/1 sar:0/1
[auto_scale_0 @ 0x55bf01fee800] w:iw h:ih flags:'' interl:0
[Parsed_drawbox_3 @ 0x55bf01fe8180] auto-inserting filter 'auto_scale_0' between the filter 'Parsed_format_2' and the filter 'Parsed_drawbox_3'
[auto_scale_1 @ 0x55bf01feffc0] w:iw h:ih flags:'' interl:0
[Parsed_format_4 @ 0x55bf01fe8780] auto-inserting filter 'auto_scale_1' between the filter 'Parsed_drawbox_3' and the filter 'Parsed_format_4'
[auto_scale_0 @ 0x55bf01fee800] w:2304 h:1296 fmt:nv12 sar:0/1 -> w:2304 h:1296 fmt:yuv420p sar:0/1 flags:0x0
[Parsed_drawbox_3 @ 0x55bf01fe8180] x:10 y:10 w:100 h:100 color:0xC67B9B7F
[auto_scale_1 @ 0x55bf01feffc0] w:2304 h:1296 fmt:yuv420p sar:0/1 -> w:2304 h:1296 fmt:nv12 sar:0/1 flags:0x0
    Last message repeated 3 times
[Parsed_hwmap_5 @ 0x55bf01fe8bc0] Failed to map frame: -38.
Error while filtering: Function not implemented
Failed to inject frame into filter network: Function not implemented
Error while processing the decoded data for stream #0:0
```

I found a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44280903/ffmpeg-vaapi-and-drawtext), but the solution of setting `-hwaccel_output_format nv12` causes ffmpeg to fail (even if I don't include the `drawbox` step):

```
[Parsed_scale_vaapi_0 @ 0x55ab1c1d2540] auto-inserting filter 'auto_scale_0' between the filter 'graph 0 input from stream 0:0' and the filter 'Parsed_scale_vaapi_0'
Impossible to convert between the formats supported by the filter 'graph 0 input from stream 0:0' and the filter 'auto_scale_0'
```

It seems like the problem is the `nv12` pixel format. I tried countless of ways to convert to e.g. `rgb24` but everything I tried just caused ffmpeg to fail.

Comment: I have the same issue with CUDA acceleration using the `overlay_nvenc` filter... if you found a solution for this issue, I would appreciate any updates on this.